# How to scale the colors of points in a scatterplot relative to data using findColours?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a scatter plot to visualize three variables: time, radius, and intensity. I would like each point on the scatterplot to be colored according to a gradient, in which red indicates an intensity is less than 1, white indicates an intensity of 1, and green indicates an intensity of more than 1.

```
#A1 scatter plot

colors <- c("firebrick2", "white", "darkolivegreen3")
class <- classIntervals(A1.matrix[,3], 10) #A1.matrix[,3] is "Intensity"
colorcode <- findColours(class, colors)
plot(A1.matrix[,1], A1.matrix[,2]) #A1.matrix[,1] is "Time" and A1.matrix[,2] is "Radius"
points(A1.matrix[,1], A1.matrix[,2], pch = 19, col = colorcode)
```

It is very close to what I am looking for. Firebrick2 and darkolivegreen3 correspond to the minimum and maximum values in A1.matrix[,3] respectively. But white does not correspond to 1. How can I set white equal to 1?

Ideally, the graph would also have a color bar scale to show what the min and max values are.

I've had success doing something similar with a levelplot heatmap, using at=unique as shown below. However, I just copied that from somewhere online and it doesn't seem to work in the points function, I'm not sure how it works or if it could somehow be applied. The colorbar scale is automatically part of the graph with levelplot.

```
#A1 heat map

levelplot(nbin.A1, cuts = 50, at= unique(c(seq(A1min,1, length = 100), seq(1,A1max, length=100))), col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("firebrick2", "white", "darkolivegreen3"))(1e3), xlab = "Radius (Microns)", ylab = "Time")
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Maybe `f <- colorRampPalette(colors)`. This returns a *function* `f` that later you can use to define the number `n` of colors you need, `f(n)`.

Comment: findColours uses colorRampPalette internally to find the required number of colors based on the class intervals of the intensity variable (or something like that?). Are you suggesting that the number of colors that it returns is the source of the issue?

Comment: Maybe. If you want white to be in the middle (at least this is how I understand the question) maybe it's better to adjust the colors manually.

Comment: I think the problem is that white is in the middle. The large majority of the data is greater than 1. The middle color seems to automatically represent the midway point between the min and max, so in this case, white is being assigned to some number greater than 1. I'm trying to set it up so that the middle color corresponds to some number other than the midway point.